# If a variable is empty, create a term without the variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a situation wherein I have a condition where any of the variables can have `''`  as the value. Currently, I have used if-else but it doesn't look like the ideal way of doing it.
eg. `variantTerm`, `tumottype`, `drug` are the 3 variables which could have`''` as he value in any given time. I have to create pubmedterm and googleterm if the variable is not empty. If `tumortype` and `variantTerm` has value as `''`, then I have to create a term with `gene+drug`. Following is the code I have implemented using if-else

```
if (variantTerm == '' && tumortype != '' && drug!= ''){
            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + tumortype+ " AND " + drug;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + tumortype+ " AND " + drug;
        }else if (tumortype == '' && variantTerm != '' && drug!= ''){
            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + variantTerm + " AND " + drug;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + variantTerm + " AND " + drug;
        }else if (drug == '' && tumortype != '' && variantTerm!= ''){
            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + variantTerm + " AND " + tumortype;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + variantTerm + " AND " + tumortype;
        }else if (drug == '' && tumortype == ''){

            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + variantTerm ;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + variantTerm ;
        }else if (drug == '' && variantTerm == ''){

            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + tumortype ;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + tumortype ;
        }else if (variantTerm == '' && tumortype == ''){

            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + drug ;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol + " AND " + drug ;
        }else if (variantTerm == '' && tumortype == '' && drug==''){

            pubMedTerm = geneSymbol ;
            googleScholarTerm = geneSymbol ;
```

Comment: Ah, business rules. Firstly, AFAICT, the two terms are identical (I find the code hard to read), so you don't need to keep setting both. Why not just filter and `join(' AND '`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a classic example of spaghetti code.

You can make your string by filtering out empty values and joining the rest with `AND`:

```js
const values = [variantTerm, geneSymbol, tumortype, drug];
const pubMedTerm = values.filter(value => value !== '').join(' AND ');
```

Comment: Thank You, You have helped me

Answer (score 0):

Robo Robok's appraoch is the way to go.

You may not even have to filter on empty strings though-

```
const values = [variantTerm, geneSymbol, tumortype, drug];
const pubMedTerm = values.join(' AND ');
```

EDIT: You do need to filter as, you don't want repeated ANDs.

Comment: You will end up having combos of `AND AND` then.

Comment: Seems like a completely duplicate answer then.